# ILDASM could not be found in the PowerShell window of Visual Studio 2019

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-2019, ildasm

Trying to follow tutorial steps and disassemble an executable c# file but whenever i type ildasm on the command prompt it  says not recognized in a developer powershell. Shows the same message when i do it for dll file as well. please help.

[image: Error message here]

Comment: What happens if you directly run the PowerShell Windows's start menu link or `powershell.exe` or `PowerShell_ISE.exe` ? Have you changed the environment path variable? What happens if you run for example `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2 Tools\x64\ildasm.exe` with the path?

Comment: @OlivierRogier Directly ran PowerShell from windows, same problem persists. I haven't don't anything to environment path variable(should I?, if yes then how). And if I run it by giving it path it says same problem in PowerShell but when I go to the directory from cmd and run it, it runs. Just anted it to run from the developer PowerShell in vs so its convenient. I'm so confused and frustrated.

Comment: I just realized: ildasm.exe is an application, not a powershell command... thus you have to run it from the command line or some Process.Start [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) equivalent of the Power Shell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell - Start-Process and Cmdline Switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651223/powershell-start-process-and-cmdline-switches) and [Using start-process and -wait command in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360889/using-start-process-and-wait-command-in-powershell)

Comment: @OlivierRogier while using command prompt too it says ildasm or ildasm.exe is not recognized (when i call it from the directory where my c# exe and dll files are, but i can call it execute ildasm from its own directory(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools). I wanted to call it from the project directory itself so itd be convenient(Is this where i create a new environment variable path?). Sorry Im new to this and if im not getting what you trying to explain.

Comment: Use for example https://www.rapidee.com (may need to reboot after changes) or direct [command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832496/how-to-add-a-set-path-only-for-that-batch-file-executing) or [windows system box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219627/how-to-update-system-path-variable-permanently-from-cmd) (also avoid duplicates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message implies that **`ildasm.exe`'s directory isn't among the list of directories stored in the `$env:PATH` environment variable, so you cannot invoke it by *name* only.**

To invoke it by its *path* from PowerShell, there's an additional syntactic requirement: invoking executables by paths that require *quoting* - such as in your case, given that the path contains *spaces* - requires calling via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-):

```sh
# Add arguments as needed.
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\ildasm.exe'
```

To **add `ildasm.exe`'s directory to your `$env:PATH` variable**, run the following:

```sh
$env:PATH += ';C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools'
```

This **only stays in effect for the remainder of the *current* session**.

If you want to it **to take effect in future *PowerShell* sessions by default**, run the following *once*, then start a new session. The command adds the `$env:PATH`-extending command to your PowerShell [profile file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles), `$PROFILE`, which is loaded automatically when a session starts:

```sh
if (-not (Test-Path $PROFILE)) { New-Item -Force $PROFILE }
Add-Content $PROFILE -Value '$env:PATH += ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools"'
```

If you want the change **to take effect *system-wide*** (in future sessions), you need to **update the *persistent* definition of the `PATH` environment variable**, which is stored in the registry; run the following *once*, then start a new PowerShell session.

```sh
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(
  'Path',
  (
    [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User') + 
    ';C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools'
  ),
  'User'
)
```

The above modifies the persistent `PATH` environment variable for the *current user*.
To modify the definition for *all* users, replace both instances of `'User'` with `'Machine'`, but note that you must then run the command from an *elevated* session (run as admin).